# Json and multiple User defined objects error

Tags: java, json, object, jackson

I have the following JSON database:

```
{"houses":[{"doors":[{"state":false,"requests":[]}],"users":[{"username":"blucas","password":"Phantom1"}],"passcode":"1324"},null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null]}
```

which I have generated using this code:

```
File database = new File("database.json");
Door door1 = new Door();
ArrayList<Door> doors = new ArrayList<Door>();
doors.add(door1);

User blucas = new User("blucas", "Phantom1");
ArrayList<User> users= new ArrayList<User>();
users.add(blucas);
House house1 = new House(doors, users);

ArrayList<House> houseList = new ArrayList<House>();
houseList.add(house1);
Houses houses = new Houses(houseList);
objMapper.writeValue(database, houses);
```

when I try to access the database in the simplest way that I can find:

```
byte[] jsonData = null;
try {
    jsonData = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("database.json"));
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

try {
    houses = objectMapper.readValue(jsonData, Houses.class);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
House[] myHouses = houses.getHouses();
House house1 = myHouses[0];
System.out.println(house1.checkPasscode("1324"));
System.exit(1);
```

I get the error:
`com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of Server.House: no suitable constructor found, can not deserialize from Object value (missing default constructor or creator, or perhaps need to add/enable type information?)
 at [Source: database.json; line: 1, column: 13] (through reference chain: Server.Houses["houses"]->java.lang.Object[][0])`

Door, House, Users, and Houses are all user defined classes that exist in the same package as each other along with the code that generates the database, and the code that attempts to open and process the database.

I have looked thoroughly for a solution to this problem, but I cannot seem to find why I would be getting this error, I am very new to JSON and databases so any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you read the error message? Have you noticed that it complains about not finding a suitable constructor in Server.House? So, don't you think that this class, and its constructors, are relevant to the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In House class there is no default constructor. Add default constructor in House class with no parameter.

Comment: Thank you, huge help! I don't know how I didn't interpret that from the error.